# Check playa count in expression engine

Tags: expressionengine

I am using playa in expression engine. My structure is an h1 heading, then loop through the playa results. However, before I have the h1, I want to check if playa has any results. If yes, then display heading and results. If no, don't display heading.

How can I check the count of playa results before I use them?

```
<section id="related-products">
<h1 class="product-page-titles">Related Products</h1>
<div>
    {exp:playa:children field="related_products"}
    <article>
        <a href="/product/{url_title}" title="{title}">
            <h2>{title}</h2>
            <img src="{hero_image}"/>
        </a>
    </article>
    {/exp:playa:children}
</div>
```

Comment: I wanted to let you know that there is an EE focused SE site now too where you can post all future EE questions: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed!

```
{if "{exp:playa:total_children field='related_products'}"}
    ...
{/if}
```

(As per [the docs](http://pixelandtonic.com/playa/docs/templates#playa%3atotal_children).)

Also - please consider posting future questions on the dedicated [ExpressionEngine StackExchange](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com) site. That is where the action is.

Comment: I didnt realise there was an EE stackexchange. Thanks so much!

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, Like an entries loop, playa will by default output nothing if there are no results, so you could, to add the h1 needed, simply wrap with {if count == "1"}<h1>Related Products</h1>{/if} within your playa tag pair, avoiding the complex conditional.

Comment: Indeed Jean, that's much simpler!